# If I'm suspecting someone I know has an exceptionally good immune system - can this be tested somehow?

Tags: immune-system, research

Please note this is NOT a personal medical consultation.

If I have reason to think that someone I know has an immune system that is exceptionally good (they are very rarely sick, almost never get infections etc., rarely enough to think this is above average),  can they somehow test this, as it might be useful for immune system/genetic research (I have reason to believe this is genetic)?

How can I find someone that studies the immune system and will be interested in studying this person's immune system to see if it really is exceptional and if it can somehow help research in that field?